# iOS application missing from notification center

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Problem:
The app doesn't appear on notification center and it is unable to receive push notifications right after installation completes and the app registers for push notifications via `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:`.

Details:

- The app usually appears in notification center after the device is restarted and after that everything works just fine.
- Sometimes the app shows up in notification center right after intallation and registration for APNs(I still can't confirm this but I think I stumbled upon such situations).
- The app calls the method `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes` each time a user logins and each time a user logouts respectively with bit masks (`UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound`) and `UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone`.
- `enabledRemoteNotificationTypes` returns correct values.
- Initially I used the method `unregisterForRemoteNotifications` on logout but I changed it to `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone` due to suspicians that this could be causing the problem .
- This problem occurs in both development and adhoc builds and irrespectively of whether the app is installed via xcode or itunes.

Any thoughts and advices will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I start to think that alternating adhoc and developer builds and installing them frequently might cause the problem. I'm still testing and I will confirm later whether I'm right.

Comment: Did you have any success?

Comment: By the way, this question is better for apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple.

Comment: This does seem relevant as it IS about programming.  It is about the methods called and the effects one sees with those calls.  It is NOT about a general problem a non developer would be asking about.

Comment: I hate when people close questions as off topic when I'm having the same problem and found the solution below.  I wish I could down vote this jerks who don't see how it is on topic.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This was happening to some of my devices. (Not showing up in notification center and not receiving pushes.)

Managed to fix it by doing:

- Delete the app
- Delete all the relevant profiles from the device. Settings app > General > Profiles, then tap into each of the Provisioning Profiles related to your app, then tap Remove. On iOS 8/9, where the setting no longer exists, use XCode > Windows > Devices > select device > Show provisioning profiles... > then remove the profile(s)
- Turn your phone off, then on again.
- Give 5 mins
- Reinstall your app, the Provisioning Profile should get installed automatically.
- Launch app and let it register and stuff.
- Test push notifications again

For us, it didn't work immediately, so give it a few minutes.

Comment: I believe this should do the job. I did some of these steps and I think this resolved the issue. One more suggestion is that installing a distribution build through xcode might also cause the problem because after so xcode fails due to being unable to start the debugger tool and so the app crashes at some point.But that's just a mere suggestion. Thank you for your answer, it helped a lot!

Comment: Absolutely fixed my problem. This is a development problem and not a general apple problem so I don't get why it was deemed off topic.  Apple Push Notifications are difficult enough with many high level things going on.  Certificates, Server side, app side, provision files.  Since my app existed before integrating apn I think it needed the old profiles deleted.

Comment: I've done all these steps, but still, I can't see my app in Notification Center. This happens only on my device. We've launched our app and neither development nor distrubution binaries ask for sending push notifications, nor appear in Notification center apps. All other devices work properly, and all devices including mine are iOS 8.0.2.

Comment: On iOS 8 you need a few more lines of code to be in Notification Center. Have you done those?

Comment: I am not seeing this option to delete the profiles: Settings app > General > Profiles

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a problem with registering and unregistering the app at login/logout respectively, from [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1):

> An application should register every time it launches and give its provider the current token.

And not sure about unregistering, they don't mention unregistering in their programming guide, maybe the app should never unregister and the server should handle that, by sending or not sending push notifications depending if the user is logged in or not. This is how I've done it in the past, and never experienced this issue, so maybe this approach works for you too.

Comment: I took this into consideration, and initially that was what I did but the server(provider) kept sending notifications although it shouldn't(when the user is logged out).So a workaround was just to unregister(or register for UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone).Your approach is correct but I think what I've done should be just fine too. just.jimmy 's answer resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I also have this problem, I found that as the application used the  unregisterForRemoteNotifications before uninstall at the previous install.

And, in addition, if the application install again and login to register for the remote notifications, this problem will happen.

It happened also at the first install(installed after reset your iOS device). if you use the unregisterForRemoteNotifications before login, then register at the login operation, this problem will happen.

**As this problem happened, you need to restart the iOS device.**

For the unregisterForRemoteNotifications, we couldn't stop this problem, but we can reduce the probability of the occurrence of the problem, the method is:

**If the device token didn't delete from provider at the previous install, then use unregisterForRemoteNotifications at the current install before login;
Otherwise, you should never use unregisterForRemoteNotifications.**