# iOS : Why our app sometimes doesn't show in the Notification Center?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, jailbreak, nsnotificationcenter

There are 3 kinds of situations about this problem.

1. During the development, I can restart the iPhone and reinstall the
   app to solve this problem.
2. At first, this problem often occurs in the jailbreak iPhone, so we
   think that there may be something wrong with the Provisioning
   Profiles.
3. But now, more and more users complain about this (could not receive push), who use the normal
   iPhone (not jailbreak) and download our app from the App Store.

So, I'm confused, and a little worried, about why our app doesn't show in the notification center, and how we can help the users to solve the problem.

Many thanks.

**UPDATE 1:**

Even our app registers successfully and gains the deviceToken

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
```

this problem may occur.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756820/ios-application-missing-from-notification-center

Comment: @Pier-LucGendreau I don't think this duplicated :) . The accepted answer in that question could not help me. But, thank you all the same.